# modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'hello_1': Exec format error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

trying to insert a simple module to the kernel that prints hello world.
but on inserting the module using **insmod** it gives the following error.

`insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./hello-1.ko: Invalid module format`

**the linux kernel module programming guide** says it is due to vermagic difference.
so , i tried using modinfo to see the vermagic of the module hello-1.ko and got the stated error.

I searched a lot but i am not getting any idea how to proceed further.

i am using linux mint tricia 19.3

kernel :5.0.0-32-generic

module -

```
#include <linux/module.h>       
#include <linux/kernel.h>       
int init_module(void)
{        
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");        
    return 0;
}
void cleanup_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

its makefile

```
obj−m += hello−1.o
all: 
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: More info, please. How do you build your module? What tells `dmesg` when you got this error?

Comment: @Tsyvarev , Sir do you see any possible errors in the module and makefile itself . i got  both of these from the guide i mentioned above.

Comment: Smells like your module-related tools are not compatible with the kernel build system, so they don't understand a file (`.ko`) it produces. If you recently upgrade/update kernel, then make sure that you have updated these tools too.